# Ssequelizejs, MySQL and passportjs user.findOne not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently migrating from mongodb to MySQL in my Node js application. I use sequelize as ORM, but I'm having some trouble migrating some passportjs code.

I have the following modal.

user.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("users", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    localemail: DataTypes.STRING,
    localpassword: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebookid: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebooktoken: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebookemail: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebookname: DataTypes.STRING,
    twitterid: DataTypes.STRING,
    twittertoken: DataTypes.STRING,
    twitterdisplayname: DataTypes.STRING,
    twitterusername: DataTypes.STRING,
    googleid: DataTypes.STRING,
    googletoken: DataTypes.STRING,
    googleemail: DataTypes.STRING,
    googlename: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

And the following function in my passportjs file:

...

```
// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy  = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy   = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User       = require('../models/user');
```

...

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        if (email)
            email = email.toLowerCase(); 
    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({
            where: {
                localemail: email
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

            if (!validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

            // all is well, return user
            else
                return done(null, user);
        });
    });

}));
```

...

The applications exits with the following error:

```
passport.js:100
                    User.findOne({
                         ^

TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
```

I have looked at this code on github for inspiration:

https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

Any ideas to what i'm overlooking?

UPDATE:

So in my passport.js file I have done this:

```
var models = require('../models'); 
console.log("models.User:" +models.User);
```

which output this:

```
npm start app.js 
> myapp0.0.0 start /home/mathias/nodejs/myapp 
> DEBUG=express-sequelize 
node ./bin/www "app.js" 
models.User:undefined 
express-sequelize 
Express server listening on port 3000 +0ms express-sequelize 
Listening on port 3000 +7ms –
```

This gives an [object:object] in the console:

```
var models  = require('../models');
console.log("models:" +models);
```

An this also gives an undefined:

```
var models  = require('../models').User;
console.log("models:" +models);
```

Update with config.json file:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "myapp",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "myapp",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "myapp",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Comment: `user.js` exports a function that returns a model, so after importing that function you need to call it (with the correct arguments) and the return value will be the `User` model.

Comment: Hi robertklep I tried that with the var models  = require('../models').User; with no luck. Any uess to what I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `user.js` exports a function that returns the model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  ...
  return User;
}
```

So in order to get that model reference, you need to use something like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = sequelize.DataTypes;

let sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

const User = require('../models/user')(sequelize, DataTypes);
```

<s>However, I don't see why you'd want to pass `sequelize` and `DataTypes` around, since you can just as easily import them in the models file (which, in turn, could export the model directly):</s>

```
// models/user.js
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = sequelize.define("users", { ... });
```

To use:

```
const User = require('../models/user');
```

Comment: So to make minimal impact on my code, I started with the first example where iam passing sequelize and DataTypes around. When this works, I will implement the more simple model you describe, it makes a lot more sense. So the user.js still looks like the one in my original question above. Implementing the changes that you describe to my passport.js file gives the following error in the console: /home/tony/code/myapp/models/user.js:4
  var User = sequelize.define("users", {
                       ^

TypeError: sequelize.define is not a function

Comment: @Tony oh I think that I misunderstood the code, and `sequelize` is not the module reference but the database instance (so the result of `new Sequelize(...)`). In that case, you may still need to pass it around. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot that helped! Now the code compiles. Unfortunately I receive an error when trying to use the sign in route: Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) I guess it might, be because of my config.json file, which I have added to the original question.

Comment: @Tony according to MySQL, you're not passing the correct credentials.

Comment: But iam wondering if it sees the password/configuration, because of the "using password: NO". I would have expected a yes and a username at least?

Comment: @Tony unless you're not passing the credentials correctly (see this: http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/#new-sequelizedatabase-usernamenull-passwordnull-options)

Comment: Okay, this must be the reason. I will try to figure out the right way to connect. Anyway thats not part of the original question, and and you have been more than helpfull towards resolving my problem with setting up Sequelize. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146497/discussion-between-tony-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is how you require the module. Replace:

```js
var User = require('../models/user');
```

With this:

```js
var User = require('../models').User;
```

This is like this because of the way the models are dynamically exported. You can have a look at your files, models/index.js. There you will find how each model is exported in a single object. So you basically always require the models/index.js and there specify which key you want to access, in this case "User"

Comment: It dosen't seem to work (I'm getting the same error), you are saying that ..."So you basically always require the models/index.js"... Does this mean that I need to require require('../models/index.js');? If so, what should I call the variable (I guess some other code should be able to reference it)?

Comment: if you don't specify a key, you can call it "models". If you specify a Key the way I replied, you call it User or whatever. Show me a pastebin with the contents of your models/index.js

Comment: I also tried this: // load up the user model
var models  = require('../models'); and then "models.User.findOne({"

Comment: There's probably a problem with the file path. Are you sure that ../models is the right path? Also, debug the var models (or User) and see what it outputs

Comment: When I change the file path to something that I now isen't right, ex. /models I get an error on start saying that the module cannot be found, so I quess that the path is right? a console.log from the user.js dosen't seem to output something usefull.

Comment: I mean output the console log of models.User or User, depending how you are requiring

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of what I guess you meant?

Comment: Cannot find module '../models'

When I use  models = require('../models');
instead of  User= require('../models/User');

Comment: @wafutech take a look at this example repo https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js

Answer (score 0):

much better using object destructuring

```js
var { User } = require('../models');
```